# Trying to install utop for OCaml in Fedora 26; got an error about installing LWT

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop

I currently have Fedora 26 installed, and I have installed the following packages:

`sudo dnf install opam ocaml gcc gcc-c++ m4 make ocamldoc sqlite-devel libcurl-devel fuse-devel zlib-devel ocaml-camlp4-devel redhat-rpm-config`

This is the error I currently get trying to install utop:

```
#=== ERROR while installing lwt.2.7.1 =========================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           linux
# command      make build
# path         /home/z/.opam/system/build/lwt.2.7.1
# compiler     system (4.02.3)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/z/.opam/system/build/lwt.2.7.1/lwt-21869-a00279.env
# stdout-file  /home/z/.opam/system/build/lwt.2.7.1/lwt-21869-a00279.out
# stderr-file  /home/z/.opam/system/build/lwt.2.7.1/lwt-21869-a00279.err
### stdout ###
# ./setup.exe -build 
# ocamlfind ocamlopt -package unix -package ocamlbuild -linkpkg -package cppo_ocamlbuild myocamlbuild.ml /usr/lib64/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild.cmx -o myocamlbuild
# + ocamlfind ocamlopt -package unix -package ocamlbuild -linkpkg -package cppo_ocamlbuild myocamlbuild.ml /usr/lib64/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild.cmx -o myocamlbuild
# File "myocamlbuild.ml", line 1:
# Error: Files /home/z/.opam/system/lib/cppo_ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild_cppo.cmxa
#        and /usr/lib64/ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuildlib.cmxa
#        make inconsistent assumptions over implementation Ocamlbuild_plugin
# Command exited with code 2.
# Makefile:33: recipe for target 'build' failed
### stderr ###
# W: Cannot find source file matching module 'Lwt_unix' in library lwt-unix.
# W: Use InterfacePatterns or ImplementationPatterns to define this file with feature "source_patterns".
# W: Cannot find source file matching module 'Lwt_unix' in library lwt-unix.
# W: Use InterfacePatterns or ImplementationPatterns to define this file with feature "source_patterns".
# E: Failure("Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlbuild' src/core/lwt.cma src/core/lwt.cmxa src/core/lwt.a src/core/lwt.cmxs src/logger/lwt-log.cma src/logger/lwt-log.cmxa src/logg$r/lwt-log.a src/logger/lwt-log.cmxs src/unix/liblwt-unix_stubs.a src/unix/dlllwt-unix_stubs.so src/unix/lwt-unix.cma src/unix/lwt-unix.cmxa src/unix/lwt-unix.a src/unix$lwt-unix.cmxs src/simple_top/lwt-simple-top.cma src/simple_top/lwt-simple-top.cmxa src/simple_top/lwt-simple-top.a src/simple_top/lwt-simple-top.cmxs src/react/lwt-reac$.cma src/react/lwt-react.cmxa src/react/lwt-react.a src/react/lwt-react.cmxs src/preemptive/lwt-preemptive.cma src/preemptive/lwt-preemptive.cmxa src/preemptive/lwt-pre$mptive.a src/preemptive/lwt-preemptive.cmxs src/ppx/ppx.cma src/ppx/ppx.cmxa src/ppx/ppx.a src/ppx/ppx.cmxs src/ppx/ppx_lwt_ex.native doc/examples/unix/logging.native d$c/examples/unix/relay.native doc/examples/unix/parallelize.native -use-ocamlfind -plugin-tags 'package(cppo_ocamlbuild)' -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
# make: *** [build] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a solution to your specific issue, but in general I recommend not using the system compiler (i.e., not installing any Fedora OCaml packages). I have Fedora 26, installed OPAM via its binary (using `opam-installer.sh`), then installed OCaml 4.02.3 with it, and then utop, and didn't have the issue you described. I avoid installing OCaml from distro packages because they are updated less often and are more likely to lead to odd issues, in my experience.

Comment: What @anol suggests is good advice. Maybe you are simply missing an `eval $(opam config env)` before doing the install but if this doesn't solve the problem I suggest following @anol's advice.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll try that.

Comment: That indeed worked! As a note for others, uninstalling ocaml and just using the shell opam file worked. I still think that ocamldocs is required to be installed via the package manager however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opam's "system compiler", that is used by default on `opam init`, is an hybrid setting in which the packages are installed in the local opam sandbox, but the compiler from the system (`/usr`) is used. See the `opam switch` command to use a sandbox with a compiler compiled by opam instead, or to *switch* back.

Your example shows that you are using a system compiler, as provided by `dnf install ocaml` ; opam is consequently supposed to use *e.g.* `/usr/bin/ocamlopt`, but installed software and libs from `~/.opam/system/{bin,lib}`.

What is *supposed* to happen is that `lwt` depends on `ocamlbuild` and `ocamlfind`, which opam installs first; then `PATH` is set so that `~/.opam/system/bin/` is first and  these installed binaries are always chosen. It's where something must be going wrong, because the end of the log shows that `/usr/bin/ocamlbuild` was called.

It's difficult to know what without more details, and I failed to reproduce on a Fedora 25 container. But you could:

- check if ocamlbuild and ocamlfind were properly installed by opam, and the presence of `~/.opam/system/bin/ocaml{find,build}`
- check if there is any global or environment configuration of ocamlfind that could interfere (`which ocamlfind; ocamlfind printconf; opam config exec -- ocamlfind printconf`).
- check the linked environment file: /home/z/.opam/system/build/lwt.2.7.1/lwt-21869-a00279.env to see if PATH is properly defined
- run with `-v` to see all commands issued by opam

Of course, as mentionned in the comments above, using a standard (*i.e.* non-system) *switch*, which includes its own OCaml compiler, would work around the issue. It takes a tad longer to compile though.